# ProgressBarCircularIndeterminate doesn't appear with an imageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-progressbar

this is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarCircularIndeterminate
        android:id="@+id/progressBarCircularIndeterminate"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/actionbar_green"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/splash_screen_image"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/splash_screen_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the problem is that the circleprogressbar doesn't appear with the imageview but when i delete the imageview, the circleprogressbar appear.

Comment: add progressview after imageview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image View is Covering the Progress Bar,reorder you Views like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/splash_screen_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarCircularIndeterminate
        android:id="@+id/progressBarCircularIndeterminate"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/actionbar_green"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/splash_screen_image"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In you Activity

```
ProgressBarCircularIndeterminate pbci=(ProgressBarCircularIndeterminate)findViewByID(R.id.progressBarCircularIndeterminate);
pbci.bringToFront();
```

Comment: Check the edit ive just made,just remove layout_above on your Progressbar,it works ,ive updated code just use that

Comment: Check the edit ive just made,just remove `android:layout_above="@+id/splash_screen_image"` from your Progressbar,it works ,ive updated code just use that

Comment: it was like that and it didn't works !! that's why i added that. i'll try with bringToFront() method

Comment: Actually the above code should work as it is,without layout_above attribute

Comment: thanks it works with the method bringToFront()
please update your answer to vote it up ;)

Comment: Cool! i've Updated ,but i still aint found any flaw in old code tho .

Answer (score 0):

because your ProgressBarCircularIndeterminate is below ImageView.

You can change the position of them to get what you want.
just like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
   ...>
   <ImageView .../>
   <ProgressBarCircularIndeterminate .../>
</RelativeLayout>
```